# Upon log in, will not fully boot

Tags: unity

Clean install of ubuntu 14.04... upon first boot, all is well. No problems to report. On the 2nd log in, is where trouble begins. Sometimes (no particular pattern), the computer will get to the log in screen. Sometimes, the ubuntu loading screen never resolves. When it DOES load:

1. Unity does not load anything in its search or applications lists.
   Unity will open, but nothing occurs.
2. Terminal does not respond to commands. Terminal windows (and even
   TTY1-6) do absolutely nothing when commands are issued.
3. Left side taskbar "works", and launches tasks, but they quickly
   freeze and need to be force quit to get rid of them.
4. Desktop background does not and will not load.

I have done the following tests so far:

1. Deleted all settings in /home partition to ensure this was not the problem
2. Tried to narrow down if an app was misbehaving - on the latest iteration, only installed chrome and vlc, problem still occurs.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

could you post your installation log, sometimes the error in installation can be small so it wont show as an error message, try examining the log for any errors. also this could actually be because your computer is not capable of running the version of ubuntu, is it possible that you installed a 64x file on a 32x capable processor?

Comment: where would i find such a log? also, this computer previously ran ubuntu, and I can't figure out what I changed to cause this problem. I built the machine, it was 100% capapble of 64=bit as I dual boot with 64bit windows.

Comment: you can find the log at /var/log/installer .

Comment: what flavor of Ubuntu are you running because some flavors are made for only certain devices

Comment: have you considered viruses or malwares from the previous operating system? which was you previous OS BTW?

Comment: I have to reinstall to even get to that log, so I'll do that next.... I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.1 (119cb63b48c9a18f31f417f09655efbd) and I don't think malware is an issue since I'm formatting the hard drive. The last OS was Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: @paperfairy that could be your problem right there, canonical has not released official updates for 14.04.1 trusty tahr, and without updating sudo the system sometimes doesnt work properly, try downgrading your software or reinstalling 14.04 then upgrading to 14.04.1 since that will download the sudo updates, hope this works :)